# gnu make: ":= $(expression)" vs ":= @(expression)"

Tags: make

I am trying to determine what the the difference is between the "$" and "@" when used during expression evaluation (if that is the correct term).  For instance, in the Makefile I am trying to understand there is the following expression

```
NO-DEBUG   := @(if $(DEBUG),,1)
```

Later, there is the following expression

```
NO-CHECKED  := $(if $(CHECKED),,1)
```

These seem to be doing the same thing, but I am not sure how the "$" and "@" might be affecting the evaluations.  I couldn't find anything by searching for ":= @" or "= @" in my cursory google searches.  Any insight?  Why would one be used apposed to the other?

Thanks and regards,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen and have no idea about `@(expression)` in GNU make.  It would simply be left uninterpreted if used.  I confirmed it by tests with GNU make 4.0.  There seems no mention in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Concept-Index.html#Concept-Index_cp_symbol-13).

Regarding `=` and `:=`, you should read [The Two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html) in the reference manual.  There's detailed explanation with examples.

Comment: yaegashi, thanks for the response.  My wording of my question wasn't the best as I was not looking for differences between "=" and ":=".  My search started with ":= @", but yielded not results.  So, I expanded the search to "= @" along with "gnu make" (in both cases).  We are using v3.81, so I suspect your result will be the same with this version.  I have no idea why it was used or if it was a mistake in the Makefile.

Comment: @lordhog Ok, could you show that Makefile or tell the name of software that has it?

Comment: the Makefile comes from an internal project (not open source) file, so I can't share it.  I had asked a few friends what it was, but best they thought it was something added for compatibility with another make utility.  Thus, I was at a lost and posted this question.  There were only two instances.  One of which was the NO-DEBUG.